# Configured the HA Cluster with Hive-2.0.1(Derby Support) shows redundant database names?

Tags: hadoop, hive, derby

I have configured the HA Cluster with one Namenode and one Standby and one data node.
I have started derby database with hiveserver2(Hive-2.0.1).

After started the hive server, open the beeline.cmd to check the number of database exists.

It shows default for 2 times:

0: jdbc:hive2://hostname:port/default> show databases;

+----------------+--+

| database_name  |

+----------------+--+

| default        |

| default        |

+----------------+--+

3 rows selected (0.027 seconds)

At that time i can't able to create table in that hive2.

Can anyone tell me the reason for that issue?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to have the same database twice.

Try to create same database from two different clients at a same time.

If duplicate database can be created then ask your query in [Hive mailing list](https://hive.apache.org/mailing_lists.html) or report in jira.

Comment: Yes it is replicated in Yarn-Cluster Mode.

If i connect same meta store with two beeline clients.
Reason:Hive Query execution between two clients are same.

two same databases created.

But if i have do the same in local mode, hive query execution faster so it doesn't allow more than one database with same name.